# Generating a sitemap that is served from multiple app servers with Laravel

Tags: laravel, sitemap

Right now, my `sitemap.xml` consists of multiple SQL-queries that fetches all resources and provides their respective URL. The pros of this method is that the `sitemap.xml` looks the same from all app servers. The con is that it puts unnecessary load on the database on every request.

Therefor, I am thinking about scheduling a job that runs the same code and saves the generated `sitemap.xml` to a remote server (AWS) every X hours. Then in my `robots.txt` I could provide URL to the `sitemap.xml` hosted on AWS.

Does this sound reasonable? If not, how do I generate a static sitemap that is served from multiple app servers?

Comment: I Had the same issue, so what we did is we have put a cache mechanism https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache and made a cache of 6 hours for our case (you can customize the same for your own) else we did one another task which is we have created an API and a python script which fetch on incremental level and create static XML and upload the same on S3 and also ping google for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I settled with caching the response. However, this is not ideal. A better way of doing this I think would be uploading it to AWS and either putting that URL in the `robots.txt` or just reading that file on the server (i.e. `file_get_contents()`.